# TracerWarning: Converting a tensor to a Python index might cause the trace to be incorrect

Tags: python, pytorch, torch

I am trying to create trace file. Related code part is here:

```
def center_crop(self, layer, target_size):
    _, _, layer_height, layer_width = layer.size()

    diff_y = (layer_height - target_size[0]) // 2
    diff_x = (layer_width - target_size[1]) // 2
    return layer[:, :, diff_y:(diff_y + target_size[0]), diff_x:(diff_x + target_size[1])]

def forward(self, x, bridge):

    up = self.up(x)
    crop1 = self.center_crop(bridge, up.shape[2:])
    out = torch.cat([up, crop1], 1)
    out = self.conv_block(out)
```

It gives the warning at this line:

```
return layer[:, :, diff_y:(diff_y + target_size[0]), diff_x:(diff_x + target_size[1])]
```

Then, I loaded this trace file in C++ and made prediction for a test image. Then I compared the result with the output in python. I observed that results are very different. I guess that the reason originates from that warning.

Comment: You are right: `layer.size()` is of type `torch.Size` (which would be traced correctly) but destructuring it into `_, _, layer_height, layer_width` causes those variables to be regular python `int`s, which are not traced and thus the indexing line works as if the indices were constant. This will give errors in C++ if your input would lead to those variables taking different values than they did when creating the trace. Now what is your question?

Comment: @Jatentaki I changed those lines:

`diff_y = (layer_height - target_size[0]) // 2         diff_x = (layer_width - target_size[1]) // 2`

into 

`diff_y = (layer.size()[2] - target_size[0]) // 2
 diff_x = (layer.size()[3] - target_size[1]) // 2`

It still gives the warning at the same line

Comment: Because `layer.size()[i]` also does convert to an ordinary `int`. What is your question? Are you trying to make this code work in c++?

Comment: @Jatentaki Let me explain. I am trying to segment objects by using Unet architecture. I obtained good results in Python. I would like to make the same prediction in C++. Therefore, I created a trace file. I wrote C++ code to test an image by loading that trace file. However, it gave different result.